# How do I Fix this issue : Value of type 'UIScrollView" has no member text

Tags: swift, xcode

[image]

This is my code so far and  I'm just trying to add a scrolling text instead of a label text.

Comment: 1. You should add code and your error to your question (not as image) and 2. i think the error message is quite clear.

Comment: `UIScrollView` does not have a property `text`. Thats not how you add text to scroll view. You can add `UILabel` as a subview to scroll view.

Comment: Please add the code as a code snippet instead of adding it as a screenshot.

Comment: What does `petDescTitle[myIndex]` return? A `UILabel`, a `String`, or something  else?

Answer (score 1):

Your outlet `descTitleLabel` is a type of `UIScrollView` and it does not have a member text. If you want to implement easily scrollable text you can use `UITextView` class instead of `UIScrollview`.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming because there is no `text` property in `UIScrollView`

For the purpose of scrollable variable amount of text you should use `UITextView`. There is no purpose of using `UIScrollView` here.

Please change outlet `descTitleLabel` to a type of `UITextView` then statement

```
descTitleLabel.text = petDescTitle[myIndex]
```

should work fine.